# jQuery find * all but :not this class?

Tags: jquery

I know you can use the `:not` selector to exclude a class/id, but I am trying to use it with * all.

```
    if(jQuery(e.target).is( jQuery(el).find('*:not(.exit-builder)') )){
        return;
    }
```

I am trying to exclude all elements from an event, there is a good reason why I am doing this.  Essentially what happens is when `<div class="parent">` is clicked the event is fired, but all children under the parent (nested children, and all types of elements) are excluded. I mean the solution works perfectly for me, but I have one element inside the * that needs to be fired and that is an element with class `.exit-builder`.

I am thinking I could turn the * to `.children().children()` or something like that, but I dont think so doesn't sound right, something similar may work.. Ill keep hacking away hopefully someone knows what I am talking about :)

Comment: Why not just look for `$(this).find(".exit-builder")`.  No need to exclude everything else when you can just find what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey actually the way my app is structured el is '$(this)' technically speaking. http://jsfiddle.net/zuNhX/4/ take a look at the fiddle. if I were to use `this` inside that object it would refer to the object itself..

Answer (score 2):

Try [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
if(jQuery(e.target).is( jQuery(el).filter(':not(.exit-builder)') )){
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks still have some traversing methods to learn. Havent used `.filter`yet, it didnt come to mind :)

Comment: Wait hold on, it looks like I spoke to soon.. the reason I used `.find()` was because I wanted to exclude all elements under the event element. I read find is similar to `.children` essentially I want to stop all children of the `el` from being fired in the event.. the element is the event..

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry make a fiddle.

Comment: Okay.. I think I know what to do.. I read up on `.filter` let me try in in jsfiddle and if messed up ill still post link..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zuNhX/2/ here is a fiddle strangely my original code works, maybe its something in my actual code.. I need to debug. Take a look and see if you have any thoughts.. maybe they can help..

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry yeah than original code has some problem.

Comment: Looks like it is more of a css issue, the div is absolutely positioned and it has something to do with that... Thanks so much for trying to help.. definitely gave me a push to read `.filter()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one http://jsbin.com/uVACoLE/1/edit

Here is working example.

Comment: I understand `:not` I needed to `.filter()`